# Android status bar color setting for all the activities

Tags: android-statusbar

I had set the theme color in styles for the status bar but it keeps only one activity to that color other activities are looking as such how can i change my other activities status bar color

Comment: i had added this line to my code in the styles <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item> but the status bar color didnt change for all the activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the values folder u have to create v21 in that u have to place the status bar colour